Permissibility of working under other's name with consent
My sister recently applied for a tutoring job with good payment online. However, due to being occupied with household chores, she asked me to tutor the kids under her name and profile (without the one who hired knowing) since I am looking for a tutoring online job too. I'm not as qualified as her although I'm enough qualified to tutor those kids but I refused thinking that it would be a deception. Was this act permissible?
